# Implement field normalization for all form fields

Tags: redux-form

Hi i would like to implement form normalization for uppercase like here [Normalizing Form Data](http://erikras.github.io/redux-form/#/examples/normalizing?_k=av3x1y)

```
const reducer = combineReducers({
  // other reducers
  form: form.normalize({
    normalizing: {                                    // <--- name of the form
      upper: value => value && value.toUpperCase(),   // normalizer for 'upper' field
      phone: normalizePhone,                          // normalizer for 'phone' field
      min: normalizeMin,                              // normalizer for 'min' field
      max: normalizeMax                               // normalizer for 'max' field
    }
  })
});
```

I have 100 fields and i don't want to write each one of the field but pass some kind of array,something like that.

```
const reducer = combineReducers({
  // other reducers
  form: form.normalize({
    normalizing: {                                    // <--- name of the form
      fieldsArray: value => value && value.toUpperCase(),   // normalizer for 'upper' field
    }
  })
});
```

how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Erik R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/103690/erik-r) Posted answer in his project 
https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/685